# How do I read the sizes of a matrix in a text file, C

Tags: c, matrix

I have matrices in a text file in the format:

```
1 2 4
2 5 6
7 8 9

5 6 7 8
6 7 8 9
7 8 9 0
```

These are just two arbitary matrices and they are seperated by an empty line. I know how to read in from a text file into multidimensional arrays in C but I am a little confused on how to get the number of rows and columns for the matrices in the given format. They can be of different lengths each time.
How do I infer the number of rows and columns?

Comment: Is space separating two matrices?

Comment: No they need not be square matrices and yes there is just an empty line seperating the two matrices

Comment: @Sam, you have to work with what you have, of course.  It's unclear what exactly you're stuck on, but perhaps it will help to realize that you can read your input file *line-by-line* into memory, analyze the lines, and act appropriately on them.  There are other ways to approach the problem, too, but obviously you can't use a technique that depends on knowing the array dimensions in advance, such as you may already be familiar with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may be a less than elegant solution, but it solves the problem.

Implement your own, special function that reads characters from the
screen. Once it notices an end of line, `\n`, interpret that as
a line. Something like this:

```
int readInteger(char *endCharacter) {
  char input;
  int integer;
  integer = 0;
  input = getchar();
  while (input != ' ' && input != '\n') {
    integer += (int)input - '0';
    integer *= 10;
    input = getchar();
  }
  *endCharacter = input;
  return integer;
}

int *integerRowFromInput() {
  int *row;
  int size;
  char endCharacter;
  row = malloc(sizeof(int));
  row[0] = readInteger(&endCharacter);
  size = 1;
  while (endCharacter != '\n') {
    size++;
    row = realloc(size * sizeof(int));
    row[size - 1] = readInteger(&endCharacter);
  }
  return row;
}
```

Of course, this code needs adaption for further use,
but this might be an approach for getting the input
without having gotten specified what the dimensions
of the matrices are.

Answer (score -1):

If you cannot modify the file format to include the size beforehand, you have no other choice than to read lines until you find an empty one. Similarly, you'll need to parse at least one line completely to find out how many columns the matrix has.

You have two choices to read the matrix then: either you read the lines into a buffer with enough bytes to cover the largest matrices, or you go back to the first line of the matrix and allocate the matrix array according to the size information you just obtained.

Comment: ... or use `realloc()` and friends for a matrix that grows as needed as more and more lines are read.

Comment: So you'd rather call `realloc` every time you get a line that's not an empty line? Sounds very inperformant.

Comment: Maybe reallocating is faster than reading from disk? Anyway you can use the common strategy of doubling the allocated memory when it's short (and deleting unused rows at the end) to minimize calls to `realloc()`.